# How to build a website which could show the binary code of an image?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, image

I am a beginner who develops sites using react and node js.

I am trying to build a website that will take images stored in the computer and show its binary format(Saw a video on youtube where they told images are stored in binary format). Also upon tweaking those binary data I could see a change in the original image.

I am trying to accomplish it using node and react but don't know which libraries to use also whether it is possible to show binary data of the image?

I looked for some node.js libraries for image manipulation but they were about resizing, changing the contrast of the image etc, but not on showing the binary data of the image.

Let me know if more information is required. Please guide me on how should I proceed.

Comment: You probably should first look up what binary format is. Not only images are stored as binary, but all other data is stored as binary too. There is no need to have a special image library for that. You have each pixel of your image that consists of `n` components (e.g. red, green, blue), and each component has a value, like 0-255 and that value can be converted to a binary representation.

Comment: @t.niese Both of your statements are true, but putting them together implies something which is not: you can't just look at most image files and extract the red, green and blue components of each pixel without a significant amount of code to parse and uncompress the data.

Comment: @IMSoP if the editor in the web browser and the OP limit themself to the file formats supported by the browser, then only the canvas API is needed. But yes if the image is encoded as JPG and the OP reads the JPG encoded data and looks at this binary representation then retrieving the pixels is problematic.  But then also the `I am trying to build a website that will take images stored in the computer and show its binary format` is not clear (binary format of the actual file, then no library is needed, but editing that binary likely won't make much sense)

Answer (score 0):

There is much to clarify to answer this question, and the answer would probably very long.

Here some code to get you started:

(sorry, my "load binary" example doesn't handle the FormData, but backend filesystem files, which is not what you want. But I have to leave now, I hope it helps anyway.)

#### upload a file to the browser, and send it to the server:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <script>
        async function uploadFile() {
            console.log('upload..');
            const inputElement = document.getElementById('fileupload');
            let formData = new FormData();
            formData.append("file", inputElement.files[0]);
            await fetch('/data', {
                method: "POST",
                body: formData
            });
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <input id="fileupload" type="file" />
    <button onclick="uploadFile()">
        Upload
    </button>
</body>
</html>
```

This .html file has to be served because of browser security restrictions, but I think you can adapt the idea to your react project.

In case you need it (I guess you don't), an example for static file serving: https://gist.github.com/ryanflorence/701407

See also: https://www.theserverside.com/blog/Coffee-Talk-Java-News-Stories-and-Opinions/Ajax-JavaScript-file-upload-example

#### Load a binary and serve it to the browser:

```
// -- imports
const http = require("http");
const path = require("path");
const fs = require("fs");

// -- setup
const port = 8000;
const fileName = 'dataFilex.jpg';
const placeholder = '.';

// -- create server
const server = http.createServer( function( request, response ){

    const filePath = path.join( process.cwd(), fileName );

    // -- load file
    fs.readFile( filePath, function( err, fileBuffer ){ // for "fs.readFile" see https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfile_path_options_callback

        // -- error reading file
        if( err ){
            response.writeHead( 500, { "Content-Type": "text/plain" } );
            response.write( err + "\n" );
            response.end();
            return;
        }

        // -- some filtering / modification
        const characters = [];
        for( const byte of fileBuffer ){  // for "Buffer" see https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html
            const character = byte < 127 && byte > 31
                ? String.fromCharCode( byte )
                : placeholder;

            characters.push( byte.toString() + ':' + character );
        }

        // -- convert to string
        const text = characters.join(' ');
        console.log('text:', text);

        // --
        const html = '<html><body><p>file loaded '
            + (new Date())
            + '</p><pre style="white-space: pre-wrap">'
            + text
            + '</pre></body></html>';

        // -- send file data to client
        // response.writeHead( 200, { "Content-Type": "text/plain" } );
        response.writeHead(200, { 'content-type': 'text/html' })
        response.write( html );
        response.end();
    });

});

// -- start server
server.listen( port );
console.log("server running at http://localhost:" + port + "/\nCTRL + C to shutdown");
```